What is the output admittance \$h_{oe}\$ of a BC337?
I am trying to resolve a transistor model problem. While I can easily get the \$I_C\$, \$V_{CE}\$, and \$h_{FE}\$ from a datasheet, I can't complete the model without the \$r_o\$, and I need the output admittance for that. However, I can't find the output admittance for a BC337 or for a BC556 for that matter. What can I do?

You can measure it :)

in these data, you "can" measure it on the characteristic curve Ic=f(Uce) https://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets/aeg-telefunken/BC337-BC338.pdf https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/bc556bta-d.pdf

The output admittance is the slope of the collector current with respect to collector-emitter voltage: -

In the diagram above (taken from the Taiwan Semiconductor data sheet for the BC337) I have drawn a red line and the text I added in the picture should be self explanatory.
However, be aware that the slope increases at higher base/collector currents (it's called the Early effect) and, my first advice is to use a modern simulator for deriving the typical characteristic. I also advise that you should not expect the spread of output admittance to be at all very tight from one particular transistor to the next and, that as a designer, we would seek to minimize those variations by improved circuit design.
In other words, if you are relying on the output admittance being predictable in a particular circuit then already you may have followed the wrong path in designing that circuit.
